is there any control that replace the data table control in power apps?? because i can't see any control named data table in insert option
I'm trying to get to know about data table control in power apps. but I'm unable to see any kind of control named so. I wanted to know is there any control that replaced for data table if so, why it replaced that control
i'm unable to see any control named data table

PowerApps don't use datatables. Data goes to/from your screens (and stored) via Entities. So you need to use one of the entities which is already defined, or make a new one. The database is hidden inside/behind the entities and automatically managed as you work with entities.
Try to think of it like Entity Framework, but simplified to the point where you rarely need to use code.
